# reactJs - pass data to nested component

Tags: reactjs

My grand parent component look like this

```
render(){ 
        const initialData = this.initialData()
        return(
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
                <UserForm />
            </Modal>
        )
    }
```

If you want to pass the initialData to UserForm component. How would you do it?

Comment: pass it as a prop of `UserForm`?  Will that not work?

Comment: have you tried `<UserForm data={initialData}/>`?

Comment: Yeah I didn't LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have this.props.initialData available in UserForm:

```
<UserForm initialData={initialData}/>
```

To have this.props.X available in UserForm, where X is one of the props of initialData (assuming it is an object):

```
<UserForm {...initialData}/> //It requires ES7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
render(){ 
        const initialData = this.initialData()
        return(
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
                <UserForm initialData={initialData} />
            </Modal>
        )
    }
```